# how to read contents of a pptx file using the Apache poi 3.6 and Apache Poi-ooxml-3.15 jars?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have tried the below code to read from **.pptx** using **Apache POI 3.6 and Apache poi-ooxml-3.15** version jars.

```
try{
    InputStream fis = Files.newInputStream(file.toPath());
    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(fis);
}
```

But I am getting the below error while building.

```
constructor XMLSlideShow in class org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow cannot be applied to given types;
required: org.apache.poi.xslf.XSLFSlideShow
found: java.io.InputStream
reason: actual argument java.io.InputStream cannot be converted to org.apache.poi.xslf.XSLFSlideShow by method invocation conversion
```

Anyone suggest what to do ?

Comment: Have you tried passing `FileInputStream` object ?

Comment: Don't mix Apache POI jars between versions! https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204

Comment: @GauthamM Yes I have tried that also. But no luck

Comment: @Gagravarr So I have to downgrade poi-ooxml or upgrade poi. Right ?

Comment: I would upgrade my versioning policy ... you haven't mentioned why you even consider using an 11 year old version.how about using poi-*-4.1.2? ... or test drive 5.0.0 snapshot (on a test system) which will be released soon

Comment: Can we read .pptx using Apache Poi 3.6 and Apache poi-ooxml 3.6 version jars?.

Comment: @kiwiwings my current organization will not support higher version of jars which may affect other functionalities through out the project. So upgrading version of jars is not immediate solution for me.

Comment: If your POI program is handling anything coming from the internet, you might want to look at the [CVE list](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/22766/Apache-POI.html?vendor_id=45) - apart of that there's little we (from the POI project) can do, as we usually just focus on the trunk version...